# amazon aws ec2 instance status is unhealthy. Website loading time very high

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using aws ec2 m1.medium as my webserver. From last two days website loading  very slow. Health check status in amazon route53 shows Unhealthy. The following status shows in health checkers

Failure: Resolved IP: [my ip]. The endpoint did not respond to the health checker request within the timeout limit.

When i check in mxToolBox
Failure - response over threshold (12.21s/10s)

Can anybody help please.

Comment: stop instance, start instance

Comment: You need to monitor & check logs for your EC2 instance, not R53. There can be numerous reasons for website lagging.

Comment: Thanks. Already I have stopped and started the service. After 1 hour again its showing  unhealthy.

Comment: You need to look **inside** your instance, not **outside**.  Commands like `free` and `top` and `iostat -x 1`... and of course your web server/application log... how long does the log say requests are taking to process?   It is *very* unlikely that the problem is somewhere else.  You are most likely seeing effects of some inefficiencies in your code, inefficient/suboptimal/slow database queries, robots/spiders/malicious users hammering your site for requests, or simply too much traffic based on the resources allocated and the level of efficiency with which you are using them.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS network in itself never takes this much time to reach to the servers and it must be your application responding slow. to make sure ping the node first and then *telnet/nc* on the specific port that your application is using.

```
telnet <ip> <port>
netcat -u <ip> <port>
```

if you find there is a significant difference, then you need to troubleshoot your application which might be having any kind of issue. 
If not, then you may have faulty ELB sitting in between that is causing such high latency and you might wanna restart/replace that.

Comment: Thanks . The issue was with the instance volume. I migrated to new volume  now its loading very fast.